# How to find a string separated by ',' in PHP

Tags: php, regex, string

I have 2 types of string 
the first

```
"/css/style.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 7832 index.php?firstId=5&secondid=4,6,8 HTTP/1.1"
```

the second type

```
"/css/style.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 7832 /index.php?firstId=123&secondid=4,6,8" "Mozilla/5.0
```

**i want to extract** `4,6,8` with one code who works for all the case

i tried

```
$line = '/index.php?firstId=123&secondid=4,6,8" "Mozilla/5.0';
$nbpers = findme($line, 'secondid=', '"') ;

function findme($string, $start, $end){
    $string = ' ' . $string;
    $ini = strpos($string, $start);
    if ($ini == 0) return '';
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}
```

but it works just for the first case

i tried also this regex `/.*?(\d+)$/` for finding the string who ends with numbers and i tested it in this site,  but `HTTP/1.1` ends with numbers so it was not a good idea

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may extract all the comma-separated numbers  after `secondid=` with

```
(?:\G(?!\A),|secondid=)\K\d+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Or8wVR/1).

**Details**:

- `(?:\G(?!\A),|secondid=)` - match either the end of the previous successful match and a `,` (see `\G(?!\A),`) or (`|`) a `secondid=` substring
- `\K` - omit the whole text matched so far
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/7JMEdl):

```
$s = '"/css/style.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 7832 /index.php?firstId=123&secondid=4,6,8" "Mozilla/5.0';
preg_match_all('~(?:\G(?!\A),|secondid=)\K\d+~', $s, $results);
print_r($results[0]);
```

Comment: Lovely stuff, doubt you could do it any better.

Answer (score 2):

To me this reads like you want to extract the full substring `4,6,8`.
If so, why not simply use a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) to extract the part after `secondid=` like in [this regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/XocjvI/2).

```
preg_match('/\bsecondid=([\d,]+)/', $string, $out)
```

- `\b` matches a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)
- `(` *capturing group* `)` for part to extract
- `\d` is a [short](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) for digit `[0-9]`

See your [updated code sample at eval.in](https://eval.in/701504). If needed, you can still [return the exploded part](https://eval.in/701509).

Comment: where were you one hour ago :P